# constructor that calls other constructors with different signatures

Tags: c++11

Let's say i have a class called **Mesh** and in Mesh i have different static methods like

```
 static Mesh makeTriangle(...)
```

with some parameters. Then I also have:

- `static Mesh makeBox(...)`: with different type and number of parameters than makeTriangle, and
- `static Mesh makeSphere(...)`: with **exactly** the same type and number of parameters than makeTriangle and so on

How can I create a constructor that takes an `const std::string &name` as it's first parameter and a variable number of parameters that I can pass to the right "make" method that creates the Mesh object?
Is this possible in c++11?

I tried using variadic templates like this

```
template<typename... Params>
Mesh(const std::string &name, Params&&... parameters)
    : Mesh(init(name, std::forward<Params>(parameters)...)) {}
```

but at some point in the init method I have to do something like

```
template<typename... Params>
static Mesh init(const std::string &name, Params&&... parameters) { 
    if(name == "box") return makeBox(std::forward<Params>(parameters)...)
    if(name == "sphere") return makeSphere(std::forward<Params>(parameters)...)
    /* and so on */
}
```

which the compiler would refuse to compile because the parameter pack might not match some make method parameters. I cannot put it in a map that takes a string and outputs a function pointer either since the mentioned make methods have different signatures.
So again how can I do this in c++11?

edit
I think using inheritance to make subclases for each different shape would not be the best choice since all Mesh object are essentially a list of points in space, they are all the same class of object and the only way they differ is in the way they are constructed

Comment: Show the actual code.

Comment: Does the first parameter have to be a string?

Comment: @ecatmur I guess. How else would the constructor call the right make method?

Comment: I don't see the motivation for your edit. Assuming that is true and the _only_ difference is the construction, inheritance would still be viable (and probably preferable). Having a base class `Mesh` seems advisable.

Comment: it's not constructor, it's a factory method

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a string, you should use a tag, such as a tag class:

```
struct box {};
struct sphere {};

template<class Tag, typename... Params>
 static Mesh init(Tag, Params&&... parameters) { 
     if constexpr (std::is_same<Tag, box>::value) return makeBox(std::forward<Params>(parameters)...)
     else if constexpr (std::is_same<Tag, sphere>::value) return makeSphere(std::forward<Params>(parameters)...)
    /* and so on */
}
```

Then your users would call the constructor as e.g. `Mesh{box{}, a, b, c}`.

As an alternative to a tag class, you could also use an enum and `integral_constant`:

```
enum class MeshName { Box, Sphere, ... };

template<class Name, typename... Params>
 static Mesh init(std::integral_constant<MeshName, Name>, Params&&... parameters) { 
     if constexpr (Name == MeshName::Box) return makeBox(std::forward<Params>(parameters)...)
     else if constexpr (Name == MeshName::Sphere) return makeSphere(std::forward<Params>(parameters)...)
    /* and so on */
}
```

If your `name` parameter has to be a string, your only option is to defer parameter checking to runtime and issue a runtime error:

```
template<typename... Params>
static Mesh init(const std::string &name, Params&&... parameters) { 
    if(name == "box")
        if constexpr (std::is_invocable<decltype(makeBox), Params...>::value)
            return makeBox(std::forward<Params>(parameters)...)
        else
            throw std::invalid_argument("Incorrect arguments for makeBox");
    if(name == "sphere")
        if constexpr (std::is_invocable<decltype(makeSphere), Params...>::value)
            return makeSphere(std::forward<Params>(parameters)...)
        else
            throw std::invalid_argument("Incorrect arguments for makeSphere");
    /* and so on */
}
```

Comment: Not a C++11 solution with `if constexpr`.

Comment: In C++11 programmer would be forced to create separate templates. Also, only C++17 implementation I know is very bad with code generation of this. But in general that's still better than string in most cases unless we process some textual input,  like parameters\properties supplied in text form..

Comment: @MSalters the translation to legacy C++11 syntax is pretty simple, though. Didn't see the need to overcomplicate the code presented.

Answer (score 0):

Methinks you have missed the whole point of inheritance. That point is basically that you keep all the common stuff in `Shape` (like location) and keep everything shape-specific in sub-classes.

For a start, something like a radius (vital for π-based shapes like circles and spheres) has *no* place when constructing polygons like triangles and rectangles.

In pseudo-code, what you should be doing is:

```
class shape:
    float x_coord
    float y_coord

class rectangle: inherits shape
    float width
    float height

class circle: inherits shape
    float radius
```

Then you construct the *concrete* shapes rather than the more abstract ones. These concrete shapes, being sub-classes of `shape` should be able to use all the common stuff as well as the stuff they add during inheritance.

Comment: The code i posted is an example, in the actual code inheritance (as far as i know)is really not useful. But i think show a bad example, I'll change the question

Comment: @user5667542, my professional opinion is that you should rethink your contention that "inheritance is really not useful". If that were truly the case, there would be *no* reason for what you're actually trying to do (having a single class represent the different types). The fact that construction has similarities between the types is almost a guarantee that inheritance is exactly what you need.

Comment: Of course, there may be extra info you're privy to that makes you believe this. In that case, I'd ask that you share it. Being opaque makes it harder for us to assist with anything other than vague generalities.